# Can intellisense/auto correction be temp disabled in a vs2017 extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I am attempting to enter in some text within a vs2017 extension that I have written, but the text is being auto-corrected by the visual studio environment (intellisense, I presume?). The text is being added with

ThisDTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.text = "AppMessages.AddError(Ex)"

....before  Try,Finally,End Try lines are added. Auto correction changed parts of the text in an attempt for "fix" it to existing variables, which I would like to stop.

Is there a method of disabling this type of type correction before I add my text (programmatically) and re-enable it afterwards, all within my extension? Alternatively, is there a method of adding text other than ThisDTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.text that auto-correction will ignore?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EnvDTE.TextSelection.Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.textselection.insert.aspx) method to add text that usually doesn't perform any reformatting.

Comment: Thanks, Sergey. I have tested using .Insert() and it successfully avoids the auto-correction. Thank you!